# How to filter one dropdownlist based on another selection

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have the following code which populates the `Topic` dropdownlist and saves it to a cached table:

```
bookingData2 = new DataTable();
DataTable DTable_List = new DataTable();
string connString = @"";
string query2 = @"Select * from [DB].dbo.[top]";// columng #1 = Specialty and column #2 = Topic
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
{
    try
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query2, conn);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query2, conn);
        da.Fill(bookingData2);

        HttpContext.Current.Cache["cachedtable2"] = bookingData2;

        bookingData2.DefaultView.Sort = "Topic ASC";

        Topic.DataSource = bookingData2.DefaultView.ToTable(true, "Topic"); // populate only with the Topic column
        Topic.DataTextField = "Topic";
        Topic.DataValueField = "Topic";
        Topic.DataBind();
        Topic.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("All Topics", "All Topics"));

        da.Dispose();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string error = ex.Message;
    }
}
```

I have the following code which populates the `Specialty` dropdownlist and saves it to another cached table:

```
bookingData = new DataTable();
DataTable DTable_List = new DataTable();
string connString = @"";
string query = @"select * from [DB].dbo.[SP]";

using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
{
    try
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, conn);
        da.Fill(bookingData);

        bookingData.DefaultView.Sort = "Specialty ASC";

        Specialty.DataSource = bookingData.DefaultView.ToTable(true, "Specialty");
        Specialty.DataTextField = "Specialty";
        Specialty.DataValueField = "Specialty";
        Specialty.DataBind();
        Specialty.Items.Remove("All Specialties");
        Specialty.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("All Specialties", "All Specialties"));

        da.Dispose();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string error = ex.Message;
    }
}
```

How can I code the `Specialty` dropdownlist index change to do the following and save it to a cache table for quick access:

```
protected void Specialty_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //re-populate the Topic dropdownlist to display all the topics based on the following criteria:
        --> Where the Specialty column is either "All Specialties" OR "{specialty selected index value}"
}
```

Comment: What are the methods you use to populate the Topic and Speciality DropDownLists? Page_Load? And, you are not using any caching, you are just using a DataTable.

Comment: @Sam yea the first two portions are executed on page load. When i change the specialty dropdown i would like to update Topic based on the two options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save `bookingData2` table in `ViewState` or Session (I won't recommend to use session though) if it's not too heavy. Otherwise, its better you cache it or query the database again to repopulate it.

Let's assume you save bookingData2 in ViewState as follows in `Page_Load`

```
ViewState["bookingData2"] = bookingData2; // This should be before the following line
Topic.DataSource = bookingData2.DefaultView.ToTable(true, "Topic");
```

Then in your `SelectedIndexChanged` event do something like this

```
protected void Specialty_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //re-populate the Topic dropdownlist to display all the topics based on the following criteria:
    // Where the Specialty column is either "All Specialties" OR "{specialty selected index value}"
    DataTable bookingData2 = (DataTable)ViewState["bookingData2"];

    Topic.DataSource = bookingData2.Where(i => i.Specialty == "All Specialties" || i.Specialty == Specialty.SelectedValue).DefaultView.ToTable(true, "Topic"); // populate only with the Topic column
    Topic.DataTextField = "Topic";
    Topic.DataValueField = "Topic";
    Topic.DataBind();
    Topic.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("All Topics", "All Topics"));

}
```

**Update - With Cached object**

Do following in `Specialty_SelectedIndexChanged` event instead of where we used `ViewState` before.

```
if (HttpRuntime.Current.Cache["cachedtable2"] != null)
{
    DataTable bookingData2 = HttpRuntime.Current.Cache["cachedtable2"] as DataTable;
    // Rest of the code
}
```

I haven't tried this code. Let me know if you find any issues.

Comment: So I shouldnt use HTTPContext as in the first portion of the code? Rather use ViewState? It is an application which will be accessed by over 100+ ppl simultaneously... Just thinking about speed.

Comment: That's why I said don't save in ViewState if you have large amounts of data. It might slow down. But, it won't affect other users using the system. Where are you using HTTPContext? The best option would be to cache your data.

Comment: HttpContext.Current.Cache["cachedtable2"] = bookingData2; in the first code section. How can I use that instead of viewstate? It isnt large amount of data but need to be fast.

Comment: How did I miss that? It's simple Replace ViewState with cached object

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67011/discussion-between-searchforknowledge-and-sam).

Comment: It is failing here: `DataTable filteredData2 = cacheTable2.Select(qpopulate).CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();` with the error: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` GOT IT TO WORK!!!

Comment: Where do you have this statement?

Comment: Accept the answer if it solved your problem to close this question.

Comment: I was using `cacheTable2` when it is `cachedTable2` and that solved the problem. Although I didn't end up using your solution, you did help pave the way :) Thanks! +1 and accepted.

Comment: Oh ok, Thanks. I'm just curious, what was your solution?

Answer (score 1):

This is what solved it for me:

```
protected void Topic_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (Topic.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            string query = @"Specialty LIKE '%%'";

            DataTable cacheTable = HttpContext.Current.Cache["cachedtable"] as DataTable;
            DataTable filteredData = cacheTable.Select(query).CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();

            filteredData.DefaultView.Sort = "Specialty ASC";

            Specialty.DataSource = filteredData.DefaultView.ToTable(true, "Specialty");
            Specialty.DataTextField = "Specialty";
            Specialty.DataValueField = "Specialty";
            Specialty.DataBind();
        }
        else
        {
            string qpopulate = @"[Topic] = '" + Topic.SelectedItem.Value + "' or [Topic] = 'All Topics'"; //@"Select * from [DB].dbo.[table2] where [Specialty] = '" + Specialty.SelectedItem.Value + "' or [Specialty] = 'All Specialties'";
            DataTable cTable = HttpContext.Current.Cache["cachedtable2"] as DataTable;
            DataTable fData = cTable.Select(qpopulate).CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();

            if (fData.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                fData.DefaultView.Sort = "Specialty ASC";

                Specialty.DataSource = fData.DefaultView.ToTable(true, "Specialty");
                Specialty.DataTextField = "Specialty";
                Specialty.DataValueField = "Specialty";
                Specialty.DataBind();
            }
            Specialty.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("All Specialties", "All Specialties"));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ce)
    {
        string error = ce.Message;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's good. Always check whether HttpContext.Current.Cache["cachedtable"] is null.