# Update Panels with drop down lists asp.net/c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

I am trying to user the select from one drop down list to filter another one, with update panels so it doesn't refresh the page. However, I cannot get it to work.

Here is the code below:

ASPX (This is below all JS content):

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <a href="#" title="Select the module code (Mandatory Field)">Module Code*</a>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ModuleCodeDDL" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ModuleCodeDDL_SelectedIndexChanged" Style="width: 200px;" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>

        <a href="#" title="The name of the module e.g. 'Team Projects'. Mandatory Field.">Module Name*</a>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ModuleTitleDDL" AutoPostBack="true" Style="width: 250px;" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Content>
```

THE CODE BEHIND (C#):
//I INITIALLY POPULATE THE TWO DROP DOWN LISTS

```
  connect.Open();

  string moduleSql = "Select Module_Code, Module_Title from [newModule]";
  SqlCommand moduleCommand = new SqlCommand(moduleSql, connect);
  SqlDataReader modules = moduleCommand.ExecuteReader();
  while (modules.Read())
  {
     string moduleCode = modules.GetString(0);
     string moduleName = modules.GetString(1);
     string module = moduleCode;
     ModuleCodeDDL.Items.Add(module);

     }
     connect.Close();

     connect.Open();

     string moduleSql1 = "Select Module_Code, Module_Title from [newModule]";
     SqlCommand moduleCommand1 = new SqlCommand(moduleSql1, connect);
     SqlDataReader modules1 = moduleCommand1.ExecuteReader();
     while (modules1.Read())
     {
     string moduleCode = modules1.GetString(0);
     string moduleName = modules1.GetString(1);
     string module = moduleName;
     ModuleTitleDDL.Items.Add(module);

     }
     connect.Close();
     }
```

//THIS IS THE FUNCTION THAT IS CALLED WITH THE ONSELECTEDINDEXCHANGED

```
 protected void ModuleCodeDDL_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ParkConnectionString"].ToString());
        ModuleTitleDDL.Items.Clear();
        connect.Open();
        string moduleCode = ModuleCodeDDL.SelectedItem.Value;
        string moduleTitleSQL = "Select Module_Code, Module_Title From [newModule] Where Module_Code ='" + moduleCode + "'";
        SqlCommand moduleTitleNew = new SqlCommand(moduleTitleSQL, connect);
        SqlDataReader newModuleTitle1 = moduleTitleNew.ExecuteReader();
        ModuleTitleDDL.Items.Add("");
        while (newModuleTitle1.Read())//Add the results to the dropdownlist
        {
            ModuleTitleDDL.Items.Add(newModuleTitle1.GetString(1).ToString());
        }

        connect.Close();

    }
```

It works without Update Panels with a full post back, but I can't seem to get it to work with Update Panels.
If anyone could shed some light on how to fix this issue, it would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27493698/how-to-filter-one-dropdownlist-based-on-another-selection

Comment: In your initial Page_Load code, did you check the `IsPostBack` condition?